# Horizontal scrolling section to prevent line breaks in css and html

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-float

I have seen this question and similar questions asked a few times on here, but how can i prevent line breaks to my floated items inside a scrolling section. I have a div that I want a horizontal scroll on.

I know this can be done by added the margin or left values to each item as shown here, this seems to be a common fix for the problem: 
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ajkochanowicz/wkqQU/) [From this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672176/prevent-floated-divs-from-wrapping-to-new-line)

This works well if you know the width of the container, how would this work with a width of auto as I intend to pull this data from a database, so the width would vary depending on the number of results.

Heres my example:

CSS:

```
.items{
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.8); 
    height:350px;
    position:relative;
}
.items .scroll{
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.items .item{
    height:100%;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-right:25px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
.items .item a{
    padding:5px;
    background:#0e76bc;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.items .item .img:hover{
    box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.items .item .img{
    height:175px;
    width:100%;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="items">
     <div class="scroll">
         <div class="item">
             <p class="center"><div class="img" style="background-image:url(images/sample1.jpg);"></div></p>
             <p class="title">Product Name</p>
             <p class="left"><strong>Current Bid:</strong> &pound;10.00</p>
             <p class="right"><a href="#">View Item</a></p>
         </div>
     <!-- .item  repeats a few times after a DB query, hence exact width is unknown -->
    </div>
</div>
```

This could be solved with an init() function in javascript, but I feel there should be a way to do this in css.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this along with your code: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7qr805z/)**

**CSS:**

```
.items .item{
    height:100%;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-right:25px;
    width:150px;   
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take `float:left;` away from `.items .item`, and it seems to work like asked:

```
        .items .item{
    height:100%;
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-right:25px;
    width:150px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: yeah the inline-block seems to do the job