# How to make flex-end work in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I tried to make `justify-content: flex-end;` work, for overflowing-hidden DIV content, in IE11, without success.

After trying several combinations I created a minimal snippet which works in Chrome but not in IE11:

```css
.token-container {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px silver inset;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  //align-content: flex-end;
}
.token {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 1px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 19px;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="token-container">
  <div class="token">
    <span class="token-text">t-bone</span>
  </div>
  <div class="token"><span class="token-text">hamburger</span></div>
  <div class="token"><span class="token-text">pancetta</span></div>
  <div class="token"><span class="token-text">leberkäs</span></div>
  <div class="token"><span class="token-text">bacon</span></div>
</div>
```

Here's the same snippet in CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVgOYJ

I would expect the 'bacon' item to be aligned with the right end of the box; instead the 't-bone' is aligned left.

Please point out any errors, perhaps in my expectations for Internet Explorer.

---

**UPDATE: Added my own alternative solution**

Leveraging a [response to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685453/2795627), I was able to do it--without using flexbox.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbeQmW

So, thanks @AaronSieb, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be a flexbox issue. It appears to be more an issue of how Internet Explorer handles `overflow: hidden`.

In your code you have the width of the flex container set to 200px. If you change this to, let's say, 500px, you'll see that `justify-content: flex-end` is working perfectly well in IE11 (and all other major browsers).

```
.token-container {  width: 500px; } /* make this adjustment from 200px */
```

It appears that when `overflow: hidden` clips content in IE11, there isn't much respect for flex alignment. Here's another test:

Restore the `width` to 200px. Then change the alignment to `justify-content: flex-start`.

Nothing changes in IE11 (`flex-start` and `flex-end` look the same). But if you expand the `width` to 500px you'll see that `flex-start` is actually applied. (Same deal with `center` value.)

Based on these tests I would say this is not a flexbox issue. In a quick search I couldn't find anything about problems with `overflow: hidden` and IE11, but that may be where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. Perhaps my question should be revisited after another abominable IE arrives, but for now I accept yours as the sad truth, and thus the answer to my question.

Answer (score 8):

This can be accomplished with flexbox - if you're willing to mess with your markup a bit. While IE11 does not respect `flex-end` in a flex parent with `overflow: hidden`, it does respect `flex-start` (the default justification). This means that if you set the flex direction of the parent to `row-reverse` you can obtain the desired behavior (aligning the children to the right edge of the parent and having them overflow towards the left).

The caveat is that this will only work if a) you have a single flex child or b) you're willing to reverse the order of your flex children in your markup.

Applying this to your original code we get:

```css
.token-container {
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px silver inset;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.token {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 1px 3px 0 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 19px;
  padding: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="token-container">
  <div class="token"><span class="token-text">bacon</span></div>
  <div class="token"><span class="token-text">leberkäs</span></div>
  <div class="token"><span class="token-text">pancetta</span></div>
  <div class="token"><span class="token-text">hamburger</span></div>
  <div class="token">
    <span class="token-text">t-bone</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @craPkit `flex-direction: row-reverse` worked brilliantly for me. I'd consider making this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, forget flex CSS for IE up to version 11.0.
I slighly changed your first suggested code, both CSS and HTML, highlightning the changed/added rows:

```css
.token-container {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 1px silver inset;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
/* you have to nest your tokens inside another div with large fixed margin-left, flex-shrink: 0 (important), and no border nor padding */
.intermediate {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1000px;
    /* added: constant amount - the more, the better
       the perfect value is the workarea width, but, if available,
       you can use the maximum-width of a token element */
}
.token {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    margin: 1px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    height: 19px;
    padding: 0 3px;

    float: right; /* added: you need to reverse your tokens! (litte effort) */
}
```

```html
<div class="token-container">
    <div class="intermediate">
        <!-- reversed children nodes -->
        <div class="token"><span class="token-text">bacon</span></div>
        <div class="token"><span class="token-text">leberkäs</span></div>
        <div class="token"><span class="token-text">pancetta</span></div>
        <div class="token"><span class="token-text">hamburger</span></div>
        <div class="token">
            <span class="token-text">t-bone</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```