# justify content flex-end not working for IE

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

Flex-end working for chrome and firefox, but not working for ie, go through following code

```css
.flex-container {  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;    flex-direction: column;flex-flow:column;
      justify-content: flex-end;height:100px
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>  
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>

<p>Try to resize the browser window.</p>
<p>A container with "flex-wrap: nowrap;" will never wrap its items.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Flexbox is not supported in Internet Explorer 10 or earlier versions.</p>
```

Comment: which one of the IE?

Comment: @TemaniAfif ie 11

Comment: @SarabjitSingh try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885534/how-to-make-flex-end-work-in-ie11 hope this will work for you.

Comment: @NitinGarg check condition in my case here is height 100px, check this code in chrome and IE11 thna you understand difference

Comment: ok let me chk @SarabjitSingh

Comment: Please only add relevant tags to questions when suggesting an edit. Additionally, you should improve the question to the extent possible, not _just_ adding a tag. Comments are intended to describe _what_ action you performed and _why_; they should not be a single copy-pasted line of text that could not be less helpful in determining _why_ you made the edit (also, it's misspelled).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE seems to align items differently using `justify-content` **when there is an overflow**. it doesn't only happen with `flex-end`, you will face the same using `center`. Any value that will create a top overflow will not work as expected.

It will also happen in a row direction. Any property that will create a left overflow will not work.

Examples where the alignment is doing nothing:

```css
.container {
  display:inline-flex;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  margin:50px;
  border:2px solid green;
}
.container span {
  flex-shrink:0;
  width:200%;
  background:red;
}

.alt {
  flex-direction:column;
}

.alt span {
  height:200%;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="justify-content:flex-end;">
  <span></span>
</div> 

<div class="container" style="justify-content:center;">
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="container alt" style="justify-content:flex-end;">
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="container alt" style="justify-content:center;">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

I am surprised to say this, but it seems that IE is doing a good thing in those cases because it's preventing the unwanted overflow which may create issues like described in this question [Centered flex-container grows beyond top](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49278725/8620333) and also this one [Can't scroll to top of flex item that is overflowing container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33454533/8620333)

Considering this, it's difficult to say if it's a bug. It's a probably by design and the IE team made the decision to avoid the *bad* overflow. <sup>1</sup>

---

This said, here is a *hack* using some negative margin that will allow you to have the needed behavior on IE:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 100px
}
.flex-container > div:first-child {
  margin-top:-100vh; /*put a very big margin here*/
}
```

```html
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

Same hack applied to the previous examples:

```css
.container {
  display:inline-flex;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  margin:50px;
  border:2px solid green;
}
.container span {
  flex-shrink:0;
  width:200%;
  background:red;
}

.alt {
  flex-direction:column;
}

.alt span {
  height:200%;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="justify-content:flex-end;">
  <span style="margin-left:-100%;"></span>
</div> 

<div class="container" style="justify-content:center;">
  <span style="margin: 0 -100%;"></span>
</div>

<div class="container alt" style="justify-content:flex-end;">
  <span style="margin-top:-100%;"></span>
</div>

<div class="container alt" style="justify-content:center;">
  <span style="margin:-100% 0;"></span>
</div>
```

<sup>1: I don't have any official proof at the time being.</sup>

Comment: no buddy, margin is not a solution, if it is in case of flex-flow: row than what

Comment: @SarabjitSingh as I described, IE is behaving like that so you will need some hack to achieve what you want .. in case of a row direction we can do another hack, share your code for that case

Comment: Great, it's working almost in every column condition..Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could refer to the following code, it seems that the flex-end works well on my side:

```
<style>
    .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        background-color: DodgerBlue;
        height: 100%;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
        .flex-container > div:nth-child(2n+0) {
            background-color: aquamarine;
            width: 300px;
            height: 30px
        }
        .flex-container > div:nth-child(2n+1) {
            background-color:antiquewhite;
            width: 300px;
            height: 30px
        }
</style>
<h1>Flexible Boxes</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
</div>

<p>Try to resize the browser window.</p>
<p>A container with "flex-wrap: nowrap;" will never wrap its items.</p>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> Flexbox is not supported in Internet Explorer 10 or earlier versions.</p>
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: make it's container height 100px and than check it in IE11

Comment: The result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VXna.png). Do you mean if the height property is small enough, it will over the container? Might you could try to remove the flex-direction and flex-flow properties. Then the result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRkd7.png).

Comment: my above code working for chrome and firefox that i want, check it in chrome and IE11, so you understant proble

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more display support:

```css
.flex-container {  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;    flex-direction: column;flex-flow:column;
      justify-content: flex-end;height:100px
}

.flex-container {  
  /* Add more browser support */
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;

  /* Combined flex-wrap and flex-direction */
  flex-flow: nowrap column;

  /* Add more browser support */
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;

  /* This could potentially help with IE10+11 */
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: space-between;  


  height:100px

  background-color: DodgerBlue; 
  height:100px
}
```

http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ Gives quite a few tips.

Comment: in case of height is less than content than there is issue in IE11

Answer (score 0):

just try to use

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
```

in your class like this

```
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Flex and IE is a common problem. Most of the times this is related to the parent of the flex element. The parent is missing in the question, but you should do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class"flex-wrapper">
    <div class="flex-container">...</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-wrapper { width: 100%; }
```

What is important is that you use `%` and do not use the `px` unit.